# Open XML file as plain text in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, xml

Is there a way to open an XML file in Microsoft Word and edit it as plain text? When I open my custom XML file in Word I get a dialog:

> *"The file contains custom XML elements which are no longer supported by Word. If you save this file, these custom XML elements will be removed permanently."*

...and then the contents of the file are just the text content without any XML elements.

---

<sub>*I am aware that many good plain text editors exist. I use one daily. However, I'm trying to advise an artist how to make a simple edit to an XML file, and I know that he has Word available. He cannot use Notepad because the files are saved as UTF-8, and use Unix newlines instead of CRLF.*</sub>

Comment: If it *has* to be some inappropriate tool, try WordPad.

Comment: @DanielB If that is guaranteed to be installed, it's a reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you’re happy with it, here’s *the answer*. ;)

WordPad is installed by default (dunno if it’s even removable) and accepts UNIX line breaks. It can also open XML files no problem. By default, it launches in page view (like Word), which can be turned off on the “View” ribbon. The corresponding button is called “Word Wrap”.

When opening files without formatting, a monospace font is used by default.

**Unfortunately**, the displayed line length is capped (at least on my system) at 4218 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit it in LibreOffice or OpenOffice which are similar to word. 
Otherwise you can try to edit your filename without .xml extension.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment at the end of my question, this is specific to Microsoft Word; I can't use another program. And, renaming the filename to have `.txt` at the end does not change the behavior. Presumably Word is reacting to the leading XML Declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`).

Comment: In this case its possible, yes. I nether use Word but the fonction wich is used to do this can be named Raw editor or something like this. I cant help you more sorry

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster (and easier) to have said artist download npp or a plaintext editor of your choice. Word and Notepad aren't going to open it without some technical know-how on their end.

Comment: I can supply the technical know-how **if** it is possible. It's a reasonable suggestion, but -1 because this does *not* answer the question of using Microsoft Word.

Comment: Fair enough, although I felt it was more helpful than saying no.

Comment: If you are truly confident that it is not possible to use Word to edit XML as text, edit your answer to add that and I'll change the downvote to up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip the file and edit the portions, preferrably using Notepad++ or vi. Of use the OpenXML editor integrated into the Word by Invantive Composition (it is already in the free version - note i work there).